# Spatial operations between WMS geometry and client data

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms, geometry

I am using geoserver WMS service to visualize some geometry on the map (via Leaflet) which is working fine. Now I have a requirement to perform the spatial operation (say intersects) between two geometries:

1. coming via WMS service of GeoServer
2. some client data geometry

The result has to be shown on the map.

What methodology should i use? Note: I cannot use WFS service for geometry(1).

Comment: An adaptation of https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas , most probably.

Comment: WMS does not normally deliver geometries, just an image of geometries in a format like jpeg or png. Generally speaking you can't do what you want without using some odd workarounds like polygonizing the image from WMS on the client side. However, GeoServer WMS does support GetMap as some vector formats as well, at least KML and SVG so perhaps this would be your route. I apologize your professor if this was your homework.

Comment: @user30184 I'm still learning GIS so I have a question. It looks like some WMS services can return features in GeoJSON format, see: https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/services/TIGERweb/tigerWMS_Current/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Comment: You must read the <GetMap><Format> part. The above service can return GeoJSON for GetFeatureInfo request. That might be used as a tricky workaround for one feature at a time, depending on the actual contents of the result. Or perhaps you could utilize this feature of GeoServer https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html.